# How to dynamically alter JPEG contrast and zoom level in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jpeg

My educational website displays single medical images (such as chest X-rays) as a JPEG in a div. I'd like to add the ability for the user to dynamically change the contrast, zoom and pan within the div containing the JPEG. I've been searching for days for a Javascript library that could do this but I'm come up empty. Does anybody have any suggestions that might help?

Comment: CSS filters might work for you...

Comment: I'd go for a canvas or CSS filters.

Comment: CSS filters were perfect - thanks. I'd never heard of them. I also used an $11 Jquery plugin for zooming and panning (http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/ perhaps? It allows you to add zoom and pan functionality.

also http://camanjs.com/ lets you change contrast.